# How can I create an edit form for Laravel's user model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use the default auth built into laravel 5.2, however my application has no need for letting users register themselves as the users are authorized users of the administrator dashboard. Only currently existing users should be able to create users.

As such, I need to be able to accomplish a few things:

- Need to disable registration for public users
- Need to allow authenticated users to register new users, access registration form
- Need to provide a form to allow authenticated users to edit users, allow for password resets, name changes, etc...

Where would I build the controller methods for these views? Should I build a new userscontroller altogether, or write the create and edit methods directly into the authcontroller? Overall, what's the best practice for building such a system based on Laravel's auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disable registration for public users you can remove all the links in views to register routes, and you can edit the `AuthController` methods `showRegistrationForm()` and `register()`, the first load the view and you can redirect to 'login' route, the second is the POST to save the user.

For the new methods on User's table, i believe that is better make an `UserController` and put your logic away from the Laravel's auth controller, here the User will be as any resource, but you will need verify if the authenticated user that is trying to add another user has the privilegefor that.

And for this permission to add new users depends on your system, i think that you don't need to make all the "Roles and Permissions" thing if your system needs only a admin user to add new users, you can do it from another column in User's table, but if you will have more permission controled areas or actions, think in this as an ACL will be a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to bring in the routes that are being pulled in through the function call into your file itself.

Doing this gives you the ability to disable to routes for registration. So instead of having the `Router::auth()` in your routes.php pull them in yourself and leave out ones you don't need:  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ea9fd03f5c5aef12018812e22e82979d914fef93/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L367

The rest of the things you will need to code yourself. A good starting point is to take the views for registration and put that into a form for a logged in user. When the user creates the *new user then you run you validation (email => required, password => required, etc) and you would have something like

```
// this would be in something like public function createUser(Request $request)
$rules = [
  'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
  'password' => 'required|confirmed'
];

// validate the request, if it doesn't pass it will redirect back with input and errors
$this->validate($request, $rules);

// create the user now
User::create(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => \Hash::make($request->input('password')]);
```

and the rest is up to you to code.